# Error Creating Product Object for Lotus Notes on event agent

Tags: lotus-notes, hcl-notes

Issue: When on event agent running, console capture this error - "Error Creating Product Object".

Cause:
Servers cannot do UI functionality. They have no UI.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

There is probably an un-used:
Dim X as New NotesUIWorkspace.

Remove the line and if the agent has front-end objects, then rework the code from a set-up/profile document instead.